# Using EnvDTE.Solution - How to Remove Source Control Bindings

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, automation

How do I use the EnvDTE.Solution API to remove TFS source control bindings from the solution file?

I know I can open the file in notepad and delete the GlobalSection portion, but I'm not sure if (or how) I can do this within the method below...

```
 public void Export(Solution solution, TemplateInput model)
 {
    if(model.RemoveSourceControlBindings)
    {
       /* here */
    }
 }
```

I've found MSDN to be less than helpful with this API.

Comment: agree, MSDN is totally useless for this

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how, but I've seen it done with some regex magic

See:

- [Working Offline with TFS](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2006/12/26/working-offline-with-tfs.aspx)
- [Build Task to remove TFS bindings](http://stevennagy.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!B2EFDBF0964586B3!358.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=87898335)

Source here:
[Wintellect.Build.Tasks.zip](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/DasBlogContentBinary/Wintellect.Build.Tasks.zip)

Comment: These are using regex on the raw file, I'm using the COM object.  I'd like to stay within the confines of the method above, if possible.